# Word for "stepping stone" or "lemma"

Tags: single-word-requests

I seem to remember reading a definition for a word that conveyed the idea of "an instance of doing something that prepares one for something else". Something like a *lemma* but not restricted to mathematics.

Did that describe a word you know? I'm 95% sure there's actually a simple noun that specifically denotes something that you use to get ready for the more challenging version of the same thing.

My question isn't limited to what I'm writing right now, I'm just curious - but here is a little more context: I'm introducing the reader to game theory. I take her through two games. One prepares her for the other. It isn't practice, it's just getting familiar with it. I'd liken it to the climb to Everest base camp. In fact, you could use that, "The climb to Everest base camp is a __*_* for the climb to the summit."

Comment: Are you asking for a noun, like lemma or stepping stone? Or an action like 'an instance of doing something?'

Comment: I'd take either.

Comment: Might help to give some context ... I've tried to give some answers without it, though.

Comment: In some contexts, warm-up.

Comment: @Starwed that would work, except they aren't doing anything. It's a noun for 'something that gets you used to it'.

Comment: I edited your question to add in some helpful context you provided in the comments, @Hal. (I see that you've already gotten some good answers, but I hope this will help anyone who still wants to answer or revise an answer to better understand the question.) Please feel free to edit further or revert if I didn't get across what you were saying :)

Comment: @aediaλ Looks good =)

Comment: "It's a noun for something that gets you used to it"  -- right, that's the sense in which I meant it.  It can be used as: "This was just a warm-up for the main event."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preparatory step** seems to fit your meaning.

Also **intermediary step**.

Also **vehicle**: you can call this intermediary step a vehicle toward further advancement.

But, why would you *not* use stepping stone?  It's a perfectly acceptable phrase for that sort of thing.

**Update**

In response to the context given in comments:

**Preliminary excerise** is another good fit.

Also, **Formative**.

Not quite a fit, but a really cool word.  [**Progymnasmata**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progymnasmata), Greek meaning fore-exercises refers to a series of rhetorical exercises to prepare students for future writing tasks.

Comment: It's just personal preference - I try to use as few metaphors as I can.

Comment: @Hal That's perfectly reasonable.  It will help if you can give us some context above, though.

Comment: I'm introducing the reader to game theory. I take her through two games. One prepares her for the other. It isn't practice, it's just getting familiar with it. I'd liken it to the climb to Everest base camp. In fact, you could use that, "The climb to Everest base camp is a _____ for the climb to the summit." Thing is, I'm 95% sure there's actually a simple noun that specifically denotes something that you use to get ready for the more challenging version of the same thing. That said, at this point - it isn't about what I'm writing, I'm just curious.

Comment: @Hal I've added a few more.  Not sure of the exact word you're looking for, but they're all fairly decent fits.

Answer (score 3):

**[Prerequisite](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prerequisite)**: something required beforehand.

**[Precondition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/precondition)**: something that must come before or is necessary to a subsequent result.

If a step is required before another step can be taken or prepares for that next step, then the required or preparatory step is a *precondition* or *prerequisite*.

Answer (score 1):

A **prelude** perhaps. I think it's well understood outside its musical context.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me there's two slightly different things here. One is a necessary thing that you need before going on to the next stage, as in stepping stone - some good sugestions in the other answers.

The other is more about familiarising yourself with the situation before trying it for real:

> dress rehearsal / trial run / dry run